# Ler apenas últimos carateres de uma string LUA

Tags: lua

Tenho uma string, quero apenas ler os últimos carateres depois do ultimo ";".

Exemplo: "12/5/2015;00:00:05;90" -> Ler apenas o "90"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ler 2 últimos caracteres:

```
str = "12/5/2015;00:00:05;90"
 print(string.sub(s, -2))
```

Separar em 3:

```
str = '12/5/2015;00:00:05;90'
for word in string.gmatch(str, '([^;]+)') do
    print(word)
end
```

Colocando cada parte em um Array:

```
 a = {} -- array 1
 b = {} -- array 2
 c = {} -- array 3

str = '12/5/2015;00:00:05;90'
op = 0
for word in string.gmatch(str, '([^;]+)') do
   op = op+1
   if op == 1 then
      a[1] = word
   elseif op == 2 then
      b[1] = word
   elseif op == 3 then
      c[1] = word
   end
end
print(a[1])
print(b[1])
print(c[1])
```

Voce pode executar o código e testar online [aqui](http://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo)

Comment: Obrigado pela sua resposta, mas sem utilisar o string.sub Separar em 3 variaveis, sempre que houver um ";"

Comment: Funcionou @akm?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, como posso agora adicionar cada word em arrays diferentes. Porque se fizer apenas um table.insert() para os 3 arrays dentro do ciclo vai inserir sempre o mesmo.

Comment: @akm, vê lá agora...

Answer (score 1):

Experimente isso:

```
s = "12/5/2015;00:00:05;90"
print(s:match(".*;(.+)$"))
```

`.*;` avança até o último `;`.

`(.+)$` captura e retorna o que sobrou, até o fim do string.